# Which are the best forums about Sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Could you tell me some good forums about Sharepoint 2007? I find there are not a lot of specialized sites about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the forums under [SharePoint Products and Technlogies](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/sharepoint)?

Answer (score 2):

I agree that it's sometimes tough to find good communities.  StackOverflow is a pretty good place to work through a SharePoint question, though!  Also, you could point your rss reader to SharePointBlogs.com and get some pointers to a load of semi-active bloggers who are happy to answer questions posted as comments on their blogs, as long as they're related to the main post topic.

Answer (score 1):

My personal favorite is [SharePointu.com]. The reason is simple, there are several real SharePoint gurus who are patient and experienced.
And do not forget, the most great place is forum/Microsoft.com. You can see lot of Ms guys showing up there.

Comment: I believe the Microsoft forum is here, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/home?category=sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has a really strong community out on Twitter.  Obviously it will take some time to get to know the players but Joel Oleson has put together a good blog article to help get started in the SharePoint Twitter community.

http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=222

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for end user / general questions take a look [End User SharePoint](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/STP/).